# Install prerequisite application in C#?

Tags: c#, installation

I want to create an installer for a small program. This program requires Inkscape.

Is there a way to install Inkscape in my installer wihout an action from the user?

If there is not, should I simulate the keystroke?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: All installers give you the ability to install prerequisites. What installer program are you using?

Comment: I dont use an installer. I only have to install Inkscape and change three files in the system.

Comment: Just ask them to install Inkscape on the first page of your installer and provide a link to http://inkscape.org/download

Comment: An installer is any program that installs another. As for changing "three files in the system", what happens if something goes wrong? How do you roll back?

Comment: The three files aren't systemfiles or something like that. The files are not the matter here and they have no relation to inkscape.